# Error on starting react app bootstrapped with create-react-app

Tags: reactjs

I got this weird error on creating react app using create-react-app command

as stated in documentation I uninstalled globally uninstalled create-react-app as well but nothing seem to be working. There is work around by reducing the react-script version to 4.0.1 or older but I don't want this. Aren't there legit method to solve this problem. The error is:

```
./src/index.js 1:123
Module parse failed: Unterminated string constant (1:123)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
> $RefreshRuntime$ = require('E:/Study Material/myProjects'/Fullstack/e-commerce/client/node_modules/react-refresh/runtime.js');
| $RefreshSetup$(module.id);
|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there is an unfinished string in your command in the Line:

`$RefreshRuntime$ = require('E:/Study Material/myProjects'/Fullstack/e-commerce/client/node_modules/react-refresh/runtime.js');`

It should probably be:

`$RefreshRuntime$ = require('E:/Study Material/myProjects/Fullstack/e-commerce/client/node_modules/react-refresh/runtime.js');`

Remove the `'`after the `/myProjects`

Let me know if it worked! :)